# What tool shall I use to make a personal note book?

Tags: org-mode

When I learn to use linux, Emacs, and programming, I asked and googled a lot of How-to's. I would like to note them down for furture reference. The tools should be:

- Use plain text file, perhaps with some mark-down.
- able to generate output, in html/pdf.
- able to search by text strings.

Is there such tool-chains works well with Emacs? I've heard about org-mode, can it fulfill my requirement?

Comment: My setup is described roughly here: http://lists.gnu.org/archive/html/emacs-orgmode/2014-04/msg01134.html. I've used it for about a year.

Comment: I'm sorry that this is going to come across as unwelcoming, but I downvoted for lack of basic research before posting.  You write that "I've heard about `org-mode`" -- please do the basic searches that would help you answer your question yourself.  Quick google searches turn up [the `org-mode` manual](http://orgmode.org/manual/), the nodes on [exporting to HTML and PDF](http://orgmode.org/manual/Exporting.html), and a lot of tutorials off of the [`org-mode` site](http://orgmode.org/worg/org-tutorials/).

Comment: You do not specify the behavior/features that you want - what you mean by "a personal notebook". You mention plain text and markdown - but to do what? You mention generating HTML/PDF, but for what? What is the relation between your having googled How-to's and the question you want to ask? You ask, "*Can it fulfill my requirement*? What requirement? What is the aim? What features do you really need?

Answer (score 9, accepted):

Yes, certainly `Org-mode` can do that. Here is [a nice tutorial](http://orgmode.org/worg/org-tutorials/orgtutorial_dto.html) that is simple to quickly learn and use `Org-mode`.

> I would like to note them down for future reference.

You can store mostly anything in Emacs with `org-mode` with `org-store-link` inside an `org-mode` buffer and later open that link again. You can even store remote ssh link to a file and later open it, the same way as you open your local files! You can also store URL on the web that is clickable.

> Use plain text file
>
> able to search by text strings.

`Org-mode` is completely plain text, so you can use any text search tool to search for content.

> able to generate output, in html/pdf.

`Org-mode` can generate many output. [My series of guides](http://tuhdo.github.io/) is an example. Or the [Org Manual](http://orgmode.org/manual/). Here is [a list of formats](http://orgmode.org/manual/Exporting.html) that you can export with `Org-mode`. You can export to mark down later if you want.

Comment: I tried org-mode and exported to html with a theme, it's great. I'd continue to lean it. BTW: Your tutorial link is also great. Thank you!

Answer (score 1):

You can’t go wrong with org-mode.  If you want something lighter-weight, or in particular, based around an external tools (which could be easier to use depending on your preference), then I suggest [jrnl](http://maebert.github.io/jrnl/).  You write entries in plain-text and can convert them to JSON—to be honest I’ve found less use for that—or Markdown.  The latter allows you to convert to a number of formats via [Pandoc](http://johnmacfarlane.net/pandoc/) if you choose.  It is not a superior approach to org-mode, simply different.

Answer (score 1):

If you want to "*note down*" "*How-to's*" that you have googled, then consider simply bookmarking them, using Emacs bookmarks. You can add plain-text annotations to bookmarks.

If you use [**Bookmark+**](http://www.emacswiki.org/BookmarkPlus) then you can use **Org mode** for bookmark annotations.